# laravel Collection to object

Tags: laravel, eloquent

How to convert the collection to object so I can access the relational table data because i am getting the following error. 
**Trying to get property of non-object** (View: E:\xampp\htdocs\digi\resources\views\admin\view-all-location.blade.php)

```
Controller:   
$locations = Location::all();

return view('admin.view-all-location')->withLocations($locations);

View::
    <tbody>
    @if(! count($locations) > 0)
          <th>No Location Added</th>
   @endif
     @foreach($locations as $location)
        <tr class="odd gradeX">
           <td>{{$location->name}}</td>
            <td>{{ $location->company->name }}</td>
            <td>{{$location->module->name}}</td>
            <td>{{$location->address}}</td>
            <td>{{$location->created_at->format('d.m.Y')}}</td>

         </tr>
    @endforeach
</tbody>
```

Comment: at what line are you getting this error?

Comment: add the full error

Comment: try `@if` and `@else` and then `@endif`
add `@foreach` inside ur `@else`
Maybe $locations return nothing.

Comment: do u have data in $locations return that $locations in controller and show the output

Answer (score 2):

You should try this:

**Controller**

```
$locations = Location::with(['company','module'])->get();
return view('admin.view-all-location',compact('locations'));
```

**View**

```
<tbody>
    @if(isset($locations) && count($locations) > 0)
       @foreach($locations as $location)
        <tr class="odd gradeX">
           <td>{{$location->name}}</td>
            <td>{{ $location->company->name }}</td>
            <td>{{$location->module->name}}</td>
            <td>{{$location->address}}</td>
            <td>{{$location->created_at->format('d.m.Y')}}</td>

         </tr>
      @endforeach

   @else
      <th>No Location Added</th>

   @endif

</tbody>
```

Comment: That won't help if the location doesn't have an associated company or module. `$location->company` will still be `null`, and calling `->name` on `null` will throw the error.

Answer (score 0):

One of your locations doesn't have an associated `company` or `module`. Because of this, accessing `$location->company->name` or `$location->module->name` will throw the error, since you're trying to access `->name` on a `null` value.

Some of the common ways of handling this:

Combine `isset` with a ternary operator:

```
<td>{{ isset($location->company) ? $location->company->name : '' }}</td>
<td>{{ isset($location->module) ? $location->module->name : '' }}</td>
```

You can also use the blade `or` shorthand:

```
<td>{{ $location->company->name or '' }}</td>
<td>{{ $location->module->name or '' }}</td>
```

If you're on PHP7, you can use the null coalesce operator:

```
<td>{{ $location->company->name ?? '' }}</td>
<td>{{ $location->module->name ?? '' }}</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `get` instead of `all`

**Controller**

```
$locations = Location::with(['company','module'])->get();
return view('admin.view-all-location',["locations"=>$locations]);
```

**View**

```
 <tbody>
    @if($locations->isEmpty())
          <th>No Location Added</th>
   @endif
     @foreach($locations as $location)
        <tr class="odd gradeX">
           <td>{{$location->name}}</td>
            <td>{{ $location->company()->name }}</td>
            <td>{{$location->module()->name}}</td>
            <td>{{$location->address}}</td>
            <td>{{$location->created_at->format('d.m.Y')}}</td>

         </tr>
    @endforeach
</tbody>
```